# Relationship between conjugacy classes of $S_n$ and the number of partitions of $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Given a positive integer $n$, let $P(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$. I am curious as to why that, for any given positive integer $n$, the number of distinct conjugacy classes for elements of $S_n$ is exactly $P(n)$?

I can see this is true for $n=5$. Right, $P(5) = 7$, and there are exactly $7$ conjugacy classes of $S_5$. I guess I'm curious as to why this generalizes for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: In short, there is a very natural bijection between partitions and conjugacy classes. Some relevant reading: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_Classes_of_Symmetric_Group and http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/415conj.pdf

Comment: A conjugacy class in the symmetric group $S_n$ is a *cycle type*, which lists how many cycles there are of each length; this is exactly a partition of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, a conjugacy class of $S_n$ can be labelled by the cycle type of its permutations, which is an unordered list of the lengths of the cycles. This is because permutations are conjugate exactly if their cycle decompositions are identical up to relabelling. Since the lengths of the cycles add up to $n$, the cycle types are precisely the partitions of $n$.